# Splitting File Input Into Numerous Vectors

Tags: c++

I have a CSV file that has about 10 different columns. Im trying to figure out whats the best method to go about here.

Data looks like this:
"20070906   1   0   0   NO"

Theres about 40,000 records like this to be analyzed. Im not sure whats best here, split each column into its own vector, or put each whole row into a vector.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you intend to do with each vector after the vectors have been generated? What does the data represent, and how is it being used?

Comment: Also, CSV is not TSV. I now this is frequently conflated, but since you have so little in ways of specs this bears pointing out

Comment: After input, i need to take a user input and run through the data set to see how many times the user input data matches multiple column data.

Comment: @Rob I still don't understand the question. What do you mean by taking the user input after input?

Comment: Are you trying to implement some sort of "real-time" filtering of the data, like for example what happens when you type something in the address bar of a modern web browser?

Comment: There are numerous CSV files with each years data. User picks what years they want to analyze and then input data for columns they need. Output must be how many records match the data.

Think of it like a SQL statement:
SELECT Count(ID, ManagerID)
FROM table
WHERE ID = inputID AND ManagerID = ManID

Answer (score 0):

I think this is kind of subjective question but imho I think that having a single vector that contains the split up rows will likely be easier to manage than separate vectors for each column. You could even create a row object that the vector stores to make accessing and processing the data in the rows/columns more friendly.
Although if you are only doing processing on a column level and not on a row or entry level having individual column vectors would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Since the data set is fairly small (assuming you are using a PC and not some other device, like a smartphone), you can read the file line by line into a vector of strings and then parse the elements one by one and populate a vector of some structures holding the records data.